# SoapUI - Transfer multiple instances of element in request output to a property value

Tags: xpath, groovy, xquery, soapui

I have the following Request output from a SoapUI script:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cai3g="http://schemas.test.com/cai3g1.2/">
   <S:Header>
      <cai3g:SessionId>aaaa6227cc81d</cai3g:SessionId>
      <cai3g:TransactionId>333</cai3g:TransactionId>
      <cai3g:SequenceId>85966385</cai3g:SequenceId>
   </S:Header>
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:GetResponse xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.test.com/cai3g1.2/">
         <ns2:Attributes>
            <getResponse:getResponse publicId="sip:+12345678901@test_domain.org" xmlns="http://schemas.test.com/testnode/UserData/TEST_NODE/" xmlns:getResponse="http://schemas.test.com/testnode/UserData/TEST_NODE/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
               <publicId>sip:+12345678901@test_domain.org</publicId>
                  <services>
                  <incoming-communication-barring>
                     <icb-user-configuration>
                        <active>true</active>
                        <icb-ruleset>
                           <icb-rule id="rule1">
                              <id>rule1</id>
                           </icb-rule>
                           <icb-rule id="rule2">
                              <id>rule2</id>
                           </icb-rule>
                           <icb-rule id="rule3">
                              <id>rule3</id>
                           </icb-rule>
                        </icb-ruleset>
                     </icb-user-configuration>
                  </incoming-communication-barring>
               </services>
            </getResponse:getResponse>
         </ns2:Attributes>
      </ns2:GetResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I would like to somehow extract the rule names from this, e.g. "rule1," "rule2," and "rule3," and store them in a string.  Ideally, I would store them in a property value in the Test Case's Properties, in the form:
["rule1", "rule2", "rule3"] so that in a later TestStep I can iterate over those values in a for loop.

I am hoping to achieve something like the following in a later TestStep

```
String rules = ${Properties#rulesFromPropertyTransfer}
rules.each {
  //do something with each rule
}
```

However, I cannot figure out how to extract even publicId and store it in a variable, much less get further down the tree to the icb-rules.

I've tried variations of:

```
declare namespace ns2='http://schemas.test.com/cai3g1.2/';
declare namespace getResponse='http://schemas.test.com/testnode/UserData/TEST_NODE/';
//ns2:GetResponse/ns2:Attributes/getResponse:getResponse/publicId
```

But I usually get "null" response in the property transfer window.  Am I going about this wrong, or is there a way to do what I am wanting?

Comment: [Refer to this link...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338829/how-to-extract-valuesof-tags-in-a-nested-xml-using-groovy-in-soap-ui/32569397#32569397) I would suggest you to search for any existing questions and then ask if you don't get it :). Always glad to help :)

Comment: Thanks Eiston.  I searched through several questions and tutorials before posting, but it seems that having the getResponse:getResponse ... line in the XML throws off all of the methods I've found so far.  I'll try the suggestions from the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that the request is invalid markup. It contains a closing `<\services>` tag without an opening `<services>` tag. An XML parser will object.

With that fixed, you can get the rules like this:

```
def data = '''
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cai3g="http://schemas.test.com/cai3g1.2/">
   <S:Header>
      <cai3g:SessionId>aaaa6227cc81d</cai3g:SessionId>
      <cai3g:TransactionId>333</cai3g:TransactionId>
      <cai3g:SequenceId>85966385</cai3g:SequenceId>
   </S:Header>
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:GetResponse xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.test.com/cai3g1.2/">
         <ns2:Attributes>
            <getResponse:getResponse publicId="sip:+12345678901@test_domain.org" xmlns="http://schemas.test.com/testnode/UserData/TEST_NODE/" xmlns:getResponse="http://schemas.test.com/testnode/UserData/TEST_NODE/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
               <publicId>sip:+12345678901@test_domain.org</publicId>
                  <incoming-communication-barring>
                     <icb-user-configuration>
                        <active>true</active>
                        <icb-ruleset>
                           <icb-rule id="rule1">
                              <id>rule1</id>
                           </icb-rule>
                           <icb-rule id="rule2">
                              <id>rule2</id>
                           </icb-rule>
                           <icb-rule id="rule3">
                              <id>rule3</id>
                           </icb-rule>
                        </icb-ruleset>
                     </icb-user-configuration>
                  </incoming-communication-barring>
            </getResponse:getResponse>
         </ns2:Attributes>
      </ns2:GetResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>'''

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(data)
def rules =  xml.Body.GetResponse.Attributes.getResponse.'incoming-communication-barring'.'icb-user-configuration'.'icb-ruleset'.'icb-rule'.id.list()
assert rules == ['rule1', 'rule2', 'rule3']
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing opening <services> tag.  I removed actually a lot of data from the original output in order to condense it enough to fit here, and I accidentally removed that as well.

Comment: Where can I put those definitions in SoapUI?  Are they XPath, XQuery, or JSONpath?

Comment: It's Groovy GPath. But fundamentally it's Groovy code. I have no idea where it goes in soapui.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

EDIT: below code snippet can be used as **script assertion** for the request step

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
def xml = new XmlHolder(context.response)
def responseRules = xml.getNodeValues("//*:icb-rule/@id").join(",")
assert responseRules instanceof String
log.info responseRules
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('RESPONSE_RULES', responseRules)
```

Later you will be able to get the value from Test Case property 'RESPONSE_RULES' which is a comma separated string.

In a request use it as `${#TestCase#RESPONSE_RULES}`

In a groovy use it

-- as String
`context.expand('${#TestCase#RESPONSE_RULES}')`

-- as a list or array (may this is what interested to you)

```
def rulesWithComma = context.testCase.getPropertyValue('RESPONSE_RULES')
def rules = rulesWithComma.split(',')
rules.each { rule -> 
  print rule
  //do other stuff here
}
```

Comment: @Rusty Lemur, is your problem not resolved yet as none of the answers marked as accepted answer. Are you still looking for something more?